# Firebase - Install app on Android 11+ fails

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a **Xamarin Forms** mobile app, configured to have minimum Android version 5.0 and Target Android version 13.0.

I am distributing the app through **Firebase**, for testing purposes.

When trying to install it on Android 11+, it automatically fails, with a simple "installation failed" message. For Android versions lower than 11, everything works properly.

Did anyone encounter this issue before? Can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Also, don't know where I could at least find some logs regarding the issue.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Answer (score 0):

You can check Android Debug Log for more information.
The Debug Log tool provides a way to view log output while debugging an app through Visual Studio. The debug log supports the following devices:

- Physical Android phones, tablets, and wearables.
- An Android Virtual device running on the Android Emulator.

You can check this article [Android Debug Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows) for more information.